# Phoenix Framework - docker image for development and deployment to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to figure out the best way to work with Docker containers in my dev environment, but deploy versioned images of my app to Kubernetes. Here's what I have so far:

I'm using the following Docker image as a base - https://github.com/shufo/docker-phoenix. When I create a container for my dev environment (following the instructions) I run:

```
docker run -d -p 4000:4000 -v $(pwd):/app -w /app shufo/phoenix
```

As far as I understand, for Kubernetes, my app needs to be contained in a versioned image. In other words, the code needs to be in the container that's generated, rather than being passed up to the container in a volume?

So I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM shufo/phoenix

MAINTAINER Hamish Murphy <hamishmurphy@gmail.com>

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
```

After building the image (with a version number), I can use this to create a Deployment in Kubernetes.

So this is a home baked solution. Is there a common pattern for this?

Comment: I'm not working in dev environment but I deployed a phoenix-app using docker and this article helps me a lot. Maybe you'll find some answers too. https://shovik.com/blog/8-deploying-phoenix-apps-with-docker

Comment: Thanks. The article has many insights that I'll think about implementing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you are on the right track. Including the code in the image is probably considered best practice. I have recently written an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626583/how-to-mount-volume-into-the-source-code-of-the-app/43627520#43627520) describing some of the benefits.

In practice people are using all kinds of ways to serve the application to a container. It is possible to use attached volumes or have a Git in the container pull/update the code when deployed but I believe you would need some good reason (that I can't think of) for that being preferable.